# Extract array from list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

If I have a list like this:

`>>> data = [(1,2),(40,2),(9,80)]`

how can I extract the the two lists [1,40,9] and [2,2,80] ? Of course I can iterate and extract the numbers myself but I guess there is a better way ?

Comment: This isn't "extraction".  This is sometimes called a "pivot".  You're changing the structure of your list, not extracting a subset from it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

List comprehensions save the day:

```
first = [x for (x,y) in data]
second = [y for (x,y) in data]
```

Answer (score 27):

The unzip operation is:

```
In [1]: data = [(1,2),(40,2),(9,80)]
In [2]: zip(*data)
Out[2]: [(1, 40, 9), (2, 2, 80)]
```

Edit: You can decompose the resulting list on assignment:

```
In [3]: first_elements, second_elements = zip(*data)
```

And if you really need lists as results:

```
In [4]: first_elements, second_elements = map(list, zip(*data))
```

To better understand why this works:

```
zip(*data)
```

is equivalent to

```
zip((1,2), (40,2), (9,80))
```

The two tuples in the result list are built from the first elements of zip()'s arguments and from the second elements of zip()'s arguments.

Answer (score 5):

There is also

```
In [1]: data = [(1,2),(40,2),(9,80)]
In [2]: x=map(None, *data)
Out[2]: [(1, 40, 9), (2, 2, 80)]
In [3]: map(None,*x)
Out[3]: [(1, 2), (40, 2), (9, 80)]
```